# Can't change passwords for technical users

Tags: sonarqube

I have a number of technical users on this system which was recently upgraded to SQ 5.2. The system uses LDAP authentication for normal users. When I try to change the password for a technical user, I get this:

```
Password cannot be changed when external authentication is used
```

I've also tried deleting the user, then re-creating it with the new password. That attempt gives the same error message.

I've made sure that the affected users are listed in sonar.properties, for sonar.security.localUsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is planned to be fixed in version 5.3 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7036

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to find that ticket when I searched the SQ JIRA.